# Get the event from event emitter of ngx bootstrap modal service

Tags: angular, event-handling, preventdefault, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

Trying to get the event from **ngx-bootstrap** so I can prevent it from closing in certain cases

The documentation providing a reason but not an event, I assume I need the event to stop it? there is an example of static modal which has the event, I need to access the event using the modal service

This is what I been [referring to](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-events)

The static modal event which has the [event](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#directive-events)

```js
  this.modalService.onHide.subscribe((reason) => {
    const _reason = reason ? `, dismissed by ${reason}` : '';
    console.log(`onHide event has been fired `);
  })
```

Reason string only, no event!

I assume I can't prevent the user from closing the modal by stopping the onHide event?

Answer (score 0):

As I this might be ngx-bs limitation? This is what I did:

> (I don't consider this an answer to my question but rather a
>   workaround)

I disabled drop off dismiss

```
ignoreBackdropClick: true,
```

changed the close buttons from `bsModalRef.hide()` to my own function and use it to open another modal with a confirmation question